# How to create a button like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have wrote this much code. I am trying to use custom painter here to draw those lines. But I don't know how to fill cooler inside them. I am using row to divide these 3 sections. But I am not sure if this is the right way.

```
     Container(
                  height: 10.0.h,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(211, 237, 241, 1),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 70.0.w,
                        child: Text(
                          "Create an Event",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0.sp),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: CustomPaint(
                            painter: CurvedPainter(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )


    class CurvedPainter extends CustomPainter {   @override   void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        print(size.width);
        print(size.height);
        var paint = Paint();
        var path = Path();
        paint.color = Colors.red;
        paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
        path.arcToPoint(Offset(-20, size.height * 0.5),
            radius: Radius.circular(100), clockwise: false);
        path.arcToPoint(Offset(-30, size.height),
            radius: Radius.circular(70), clockwise: true);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);   }
    
      }
```

[image: Image Link]

Comment: Why not use something like `IconButton` and add an image instead of creating it yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this with custom painter you can edit the values to customize the shape
[image]

Add this as a body of your Widget

```
Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue.shade50,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.blue.shade50,
                child: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 70,
              height: 50,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 70,
                    height: 50,
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: buttonBackground(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(.8,1),
                      child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded), onPressed: (){})),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

And you can change the value and color of the button background in this class

```
    class buttonBackground extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var sw = size.width;
    var sh = size.height;
    var paint = Paint();

    Path mainBackground = Path();
    mainBackground.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, sw, sh));
    paint.color = Colors.blue.shade50;
    canvas.drawPath(mainBackground, paint);

    Path greyWave = Path();
    greyWave.lineTo(sw, 0);
    greyWave.lineTo(sw, sh);
    greyWave.cubicTo(sw * 0.15, sh, sw * 0.5, sh, sw * .6, sh * 0.5);
    greyWave.cubicTo(sw * 0.92, sh * 01.2, 0, sh * 0.15, sh * .4, sh * 0);
    greyWave.close();
    paint.color = Colors.blue.shade200;
    canvas.drawPath(greyWave, paint);

    Path blueWave2 = Path();
    greyWave.lineTo(sw, 0);
    greyWave.lineTo(sw, sh);
    greyWave.cubicTo(sw * 0.05, sh, sw * 0.3, sh, sw * .4, sh * 0.5);
    greyWave.cubicTo(sw * 0.62, sh * 0.92, 0, sh * 0.15, sh * .3, sh * 0);
    greyWave.close();
    paint.color = Colors.blue.withOpacity(.3);
    canvas.drawPath(greyWave, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access right now in an IDE to write flutter code. But I guess you can use a GestureDetector where inside of it you can add the button functionality in the onTap argument and as a child you can use the Image that you have created and want to use for the button.

Something like this below:

```
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {print('put a method here that runs the code that you want to be executed on tap');},
child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('path/to/your/img'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    height: 30,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Good Idea, thank you,